# Python use args/kwargs as json path parameters

Tags: python, json, edit

I wanna pass args/kwargs to return the json internal values, and edit, like the code bellow

```
path_list = [['APP'], ['CONFIG']]

def write_json_value(json_file, *kwargs, string):
     with open(json_file, 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data[kwargs] = str(string)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f)
        f.truncate()
```

I really need to know if it's possible.

The objective is: pass the json keys, and the variable to edit in the json.

Comment: Show an example of how you would use that.  It isn't quite clear.  You can certainly add the contents of `kwargs` to an existing dictionary, but I want to see your example and what its output would look like.

Comment: It may be you are looking for `data.update( kwargs )`.

Comment: Actually, `*kwargs`, despite the name, is a tuple, not a `dict`.

Comment: Maybe `data.update(dict.from_keys(kwargs, string))`?